# Creating a valid signed request to an AWS ES instance from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to find an example of how to connect to an AWS ES instance in node.js, and then hit the ES cluster with a simple request.

I'm attempting to use the [elasticsearch node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch), along with an open source addon called [http-aws-es](https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es) to do this.

I have configured my aws ES access policy to look like the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "example-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:<account-id>:domain/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "example-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:<account-id>:domain/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "<my-ip>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, I would like to be able to issue put and get requests on the es instance from either an ip address or from an IAM user linked to my aws account.

I have the following code that attempts this in node.js:

```
var aws_access_key = 'example';
var aws_secret_key = 'key';

var es = require('elasticsearch').Client({
    hosts: 'example-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com',
    connectionClass: require('http-aws-es'),
    amazonES: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        accessKey: aws_access_key,
        secretKey: aws_secret_key
    }
});

es.ping({
    // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
    requestTimeout: Infinity,

    // undocumented params are appended to the query string
    hello: "elasticsearch!"
}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
    } else {
        console.log('All is well');
    }
});
```

Which currently returns an authorization error:

```
{ [Error: Authorization Exception]
  status: 403,
  displayName: 'AuthorizationException',
  message: 'Authorization Exception' }
```

I've yet to see a working example of using an aws ES instance by using a signed policy in node.js. Anyone have insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had done almost everything correctly in my question, except for one step.

The IAM user associated with the `aws_access_key` and `aws_secret_key` in the code above must have specific permissions to interact with the elastic search instances. So I logged in to the AWS console and added the following policy to the IAM users that would need to interact with the elasticsearch instance

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1480915344000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "es:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:<account-id>:domain/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The solution works. I tried to grant ReadOnly access (`es:Get*`, `es:List*`, `es:Describe*`, `es:ESHttpHead`, `es:ESHttpGet`) for my search request but it was not enough. It must be full access (`es:*`).