# Add aws lambda permissions to aws elasticsearch policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I added the following IP access restriction to my aws elasticsearch access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:000000000000:domain/tst/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "XX.XX.XX.XX"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a lambda function and a kinesis firehouse reading and writing the elasticsearch index. How could I add lambda and kenesis firehouse permisions to my elasticsearch access policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved as follows:

1. Adding the following policy to aws elasticsearch:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/admin"
         },
         "Action": "es: *",
         "Resource": "example-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:<account-id>:domain/ *"
       },
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": " * "
         },
         "Action": "es:*",
         "Resource": "example-domain.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:<account-id>:domain/ *",
         "Condition": {
           "IpAddress": {
             "aws:SourceIp": "<my-ip>"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Adding at the IAM user with the security credentials the following policy:

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "elasticsearchFullAccess",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "es: *"
               ],
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:<account-id>:domain/ *"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Sign requests using [this](https://github.com/TheDeveloper/http-aws-es).

I solved this thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967394/creating-a-valid-signed-request-to-an-aws-es-instance-from-node-js) question